# Module is in correct folder, but still says that it cannot be found

Tags: python, import, libraries

I have pygame and numpy in the same folder. I can import pygame, but I can only import numpy in the terminal, not even in the IDLE. If I try to import numpy anywhere else, I get this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I can also still import pygame into the terminal. Also, python in the terminal is version 3.7.5, but in the IDLE it's 3.6.6. Not sure if that's related.
All of my modules are in the default path folder.

Comment: why do you keep it in folder - install it using `pip install pygame numpy`

Comment: if you have many Pythons then you have to install for every Python separatelly. You may have `pip3.7` and `pip3.6` for this or you can use `python3.6 -m pip install ...` and `python3.7 -m pip install ...` You can also check if you don't have aready `pygame` in both versions and `numpy` on in one version - `pip3.6 list`, `pip3.7 list`

Comment: I do use pip install, and I have uninstalled and installed both. Still doesn't work. Also, pip3.6 and pip3.7 don't work, only pip list. When I use pip list, both numpy and pygame show up.

Comment: every Python has own folder for modules. If `pip` installed for 3.6 and you run code with 3.7 then you will not have these modules. Check `pip -V` to see for what Python it installs modules. The simplest method is to use Python (which you use to run code) to run `python -m pip install ...` and then it will install module for correct Python.